# convert html jquery contact form to asp.net

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

i have created a contact form in html5 with bootstrap and jquery.
this form have fields that are hidden and they show up only when the person select radio button. 
i made validation and everything that the form wont demand the hidden fields to be filled and is working find. 
when i got to the part that i need to add php to the form to be able to send emails and get them to my email, i got told that the servers in our place don't support PHP and i was basically told to convert it all to C# (asp.net) and make all the inputs dynamic instead of statics.

i know some basic asp.net like how to create dynamic inputs, but i have no clue how to convert what i did to asp.net and keep it the way i built it in html5 and jquery.

please help me out on how should i approach this.

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
            form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
                form.classList.add('was-validated');
            }, false);
        });
    }, false);

})();

$(document).ready(function () {


    $("#firstOption").hide().find(':input').attr('required', false);
    $("#secOption").hide().find(':input').attr('required', false);
    $("#thirdOption").hide().find(':input').attr('required', false);

    $("#sign1").click(function () {
        $("#firstOption").show().find(':input').attr('required', true);
        $("input.notaMust").show().attr('required', false);
        $("#secOption").hide();
        $("#thirdOption").hide();
    });
    $("#sign2").click(function () {
        $("#firstOption").hide();
        $("#secOption").show().find(':input').attr('required', true);
        $("input.notaMust").show().attr('required', false);
        $("#thirdOption").hide();
    });
    $("#sign3").click(function () {
        $("#firstOption").hide();
        $("#secOption").hide();
        $("#thirdOption").show().find(':input').attr('required', true);
    });
    $("#sign4").click(function () {
        $("#firstOption").hide();
        $("#secOption").hide();
        $("#thirdOption").hide();
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="styles/myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />


  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="jScripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="jscripts/JavaScript.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <main class="my-form">
    <div class="cotainer">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="card">
            <h1>
              הרשמות לעמותה
            </h1>
            <div class="card-body">
              <!--onsubmit="return validform()"-->
              <form name="my-form" class="needs-validation" novalidate method="post" role="form">
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="first_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">שם פרטי</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" id="first_name" class="form-control" name="first-name" placeholder="חובה" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="last_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">שם משפחה</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" id="last_name" class="form-control" name="last-name" placeholder="חובה" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="phone_number" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">טלפון נייד</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="tel" id="phone_number" class="form-control" name="phoneNum" placeholder="חובה" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="email_address" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">דוא"ל</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="email" id="email_address" class="form-control" placeholder="חובה" name="email-address" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                  הרשמה ל:
                </p>
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                  <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="sign1" name="signTo">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="sign1">
                                        הרשמה לעמותה
                                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                  <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="sign2" name="signTo">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="sign2">
                                        הרשמה לגמלאים
                                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                  <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="sign3" name="signTo">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="sign3">
                                        הרשמה לפעילויות העמותה
                                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                  <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="sign4" name="signTo" checked="checked">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="sign4">
                                        הרשמה לדיוור ישיר
                                    </label>
                </div>
                <section>
                  <!--הרשמה לעמותה-->
                  <article id="firstOption">
                    <h2>
                      הרשמה לעמותה
                    </h2>
                    <p>על מנת להירשם / להצטרף לעמותה עליך: <br /> 1. למלא את הפרטים בטופס המקוון ולשלוח ע"י לחיצת כפתור (שלח) <br /> 2. להוריד ולמלא את הטופס המצ"ב ולשלוח / לפקסס לגזברות בבית החולים בו הנך עובד/ת</p>
                    <a href="http://www.apni.co.il/download/297/">להורדת קובץ הרשמה לעמותה</a>
                    <p>
                      ** לאחר הצטרפותך לעמותה ייעשה שימוש בייפוי הכוח לצורך גביית דמי חבר שנתיים.
                    </p>
                    <h3>
                      טופס הצטרפות לעמותה
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                      מילוי הטופס ושליחתו מהווה הצהרה: <br />"אני מבקש להיות חבר בעמותה. מטרות העמותה ותקוננה ידועים לי במידה ואתקבל כחבר בעמותה הנני מתחייב לקיים את הוראות התקנון ואת החלטת האסיפה הכללית של העמותה".
                    </p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="joinDate" class="col-3 col-form-label">
                                                תאריך הצטרפות לעמותה
                                            </label>
                      <br />
                      <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input class="form-control" type="date" value="2019-08-19" id="joinDate" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="id_number" class="col-3 col-form-label text-md-right">תעודת זהות</label>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" id="id_number" class="form-control" placeholder="חובה" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="year_number1" class="col-3 col-form-label text-md-right">שנת לידה</label>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" id="year_number1" class="form-control" placeholder="חובה" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="workplace" class="col-3 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                                מקום עבודה
                                            </label>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" id="workplace" class="form-control" placeholder="חובה" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="job_posit" class="col-3 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                                תפקיד
                                            </label>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" id="job_posit" class="form-control" placeholder="חובה" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="workplace_adr" class="col-3 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                                כתובת מגורים
                                            </label>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" id="workplace_adr" class="form-control" placeholder="חובה" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="mikud" class="col-3 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                                מיקוד
                                            </label>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" id="mikud" class="form-control notaMust">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>
                      קורס בבריאות הנפש:
                    </p>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="courseStatus" name="course">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="courseStatus">
                                                כן
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="courseStatus1" name="course" checked="checked">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="courseStatus1">
                                                לא
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <p>
                      תואר:
                    </p>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="degreeStatus" name="degree" checked="checked">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="degreeStatus">
                                                ראשון
                                            </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="degreeStatus2" name="degree">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="degreeStatus2">
                                                שני
                                            </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="degreeStatus3" name="degree">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="degreeStatus3">
                                                דוקטור
                                            </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="degreeStatus4" name="degree">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="degreeStatus4">
                                                ללא
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="otherEdu" class="col-3 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                                השכלה אחרת
                                            </label>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" id="otherEdu" class="form-control notaMust" placeholder="">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="mustAgree1" class="col-5 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                                יפוי כח בלתי חוזר: אני הח"מ בדירוג האחים מצהיר/ה שהנני חבר/ה בעמותה לסיעוד פסיכיאטרי. <br />על החתום:
                                            </label>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" id="mustAgree1" class="form-control" placeholder="חובה" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="mustAgree2" class="col-5 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                                בהתאם להסכם הקיבוצי אני, מבקש/ת לשלם לעמותה דמי החבר עבורי החל משנה זו ואילך. <br />על החתום:
                                            </label>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" id="mustAgree2" class="form-control" placeholder="חובה" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </article>
                  <!--הרשמה לגמלאים-->
                  <article id="secOption">
                    <h2>
                      הרשמה לגמלאים
                    </h2>
                    <p>על מנת להרשם / להצטרף לעמותה עליך למלא את הפרטים בטופס המקוון ולשלוח ע"י לחיצת כפתור (שליחה)</p>
                    <a href="http://www.apni.co.il/download/310/">להורדת טופס הרשמה לעמותה - גימלאים</a>
                    <p>ולשליחתו בדואר רגיל</p>
                    <strong>

                                            בהתאם להחלטת הנהלת העמותה תשלום דמי החבר לגמלאי יהיה 50% מהסכום המקובל.
                                            בנוסף, התשלום לגמלאי חבר עמותה עבור כנסים יהיה 50% מתעריף הכנס.

                                        </strong>

                    <p>
                      <br />
                      <b>
                                                את התשלום יש להעביר לכבוד:
                                            </b><br /> העמותה לסיעוד פסיכיאטרי בישראל מרכז לבריאות הנפש לב השרון פרדסיה ת.ד. 90000 נתניה 42100.
                    </p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="dateSent" class="col-3 col-form-label">
                                                תאריך שליחת הטופס
                                            </label>
                      <br />
                      <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input class="form-control" type="date" value="2019-08-19" id="dateSent" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="id_number1" class="col-3 col-form-label text-md-right">תעודת זהות</label>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" id="id_number1" class="form-control" placeholder="חובה" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>
                      מין:
                    </p>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="male" name="gender">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="male">
                                                זכר
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="female" name="gender" checked="checked">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="female">
                                                נקבה
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="year_number" class="col-3 col-form-label text-md-right">שנת לידה</label>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" id="year_number" class="form-control" placeholder="חובה" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="home_adr" class="col-3 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                                כתובת מגורים
                                            </label>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" id="home_adr" class="form-control" placeholder="חובה" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="mikud1" class="col-3 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                                מיקוד
                                            </label>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" id="mikud1" class="form-control notaMust">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </article>
                  <!--הרשמה לפעילויות-->
                  <article id="thirdOption">
                    <h2>הרשמה לפעילויות העמותה<br /> (כנסים, ימי עיון, קורסים, סדנאות, השתלמויות)</h2>
                    <p>
                      על מנת להרשם לפעילות העמותה עליך למלא את הפרטים בטופס המקוון ולשלוח ע"י לחיצת כפתור (שלח)
                    </p>
                    <strong>
                                            **חשוב - למלא את שם הפעילות הרצויה בצורה ברורה
                                        </strong>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="home_adr1" class="col-3 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                                כתובת מגורים
                                            </label>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" id="home_adr1" class="form-control" placeholder="חובה" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="workAdr" class="col-3 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                                מקום עבודה
                                            </label>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" id="workAdr" class="form-control" placeholder="חובה" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="activitySelect">סוג הפעילות</label>
                      <select class="form-control col-3" id="activitySelect" required>
                        <option>כנס</option>
                        <option>יום עיון</option>
                        <option>קורס</option>
                        <option>השתלמות</option>
                        <option>סדנא</option>
                        <option>אחר</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="describeActivity">שם הפעילות</label>
                      <textarea class="form-control col-3" id="describeActivity" rows="3" placeholder="חובה" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="activityDate" class="col-3 col-form-label">
                                                תאריך הפעילות
                                            </label>
                      <br />
                      <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input class="form-control" type="date" value="2019-08-19" id="activityDate" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>
                      חבר עמותה
                    </p>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="membershipy" name="membership" checked="checked">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="membershipy">
                                                כן
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="membershipn" name="membership">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="membershipn">
                                                לא
                                            </label>
                    </div>
                  </article>
                </section>
                <!--שליחה-->
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                  <input type="submit" id="sendForm" class="btn btn-primary" value="שליחה">
                </div>

              </form>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a ASP.Net page, to handle the form data and send the mail, while this html page being kept as it is. I think that would be pretty much easier for you!

I will explain. Right now, you have a HTML page with all the form fields and validations code and things. So when User fills in the data, and tries to submit the data, send it via AJAX ([jQuery AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) to an ASP.Net page (eg: `process.aspx`)

In that `process.aspx` (ASP.Net file), you can read the form data submitted by the User, do any server side validations, send the mail or insert to database, etc. and then return a response. So in your html page (from which the AJAX call was made), you could read this response and perform the specific action (say, display a success/error message or redirect to another page, etc.). So you only have to code one ASP.Net page. What you coded so far will remain intact!

So, I think it would be better if you invest some time in reading tutorials related to ASP.Net and try to implement it. And when you encounter any problems while implementation, you can post your specific problem here. :)

Regarding the server, it is possible to install PHP in a Windows server (assuming it is not a Shared Hosting or something). Though PHP will perform better in Linux environment.

Hope it helps!

Comment: wow! didnt knew its possible to keep all i built and add asp.net to it.
i will try searching how i implement ajax and asp.net into this form and hopefully it will work. didn't study ajax, json and asp.net to that lvl